# Scala case statement failing

Tags: scala

I'm trying the following:

```
def getStatus: MyStatus = {
  (mPending, mPublished) match {
    case (None, None) => MyStatus.inactive
    case (pending: Option[Edit], None) => MyStatus.neverPublished
    case (None, published: Option[Edit]) => if (published.get.isSuspended) MyStatus.suspended else MyStatus.published
    case (pending: Option[Edit], published: Option[Edit]) =>
      if (published.get.isSuspended)
        MyStatus.suspendedWithChanges
      else
        MyStatus.publishedWithChanges
  }
}
```

As far as I can see, if it gets to the last `case`, neither `Option` should be `None`, but I get the following:

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[ClassCastException: null]
....
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.None$ cannot be cast to com.fredley.Edit
```

thrown on `if (published.get.isSuspended)`. What's going on?

Comment: You are ascripting the type, try to remove the `: Option[Edit]` part, it may be that you are not getting the type you expect, if those variable are options in your match there should be `None` and `Some(value)`, unless you have an option of option. For the exception, that happens on the get because of the fact that you are matching `Option[Edit]`, but `None` is a valid match for that type.

Comment: To rephrase Ende Neu, use `Some(edit: Edit)` to extract nonempty option. But the weird CCE suggests you have a nested option.

Comment: Is `MyStatus` an alias to `(Option[Edit], Option[Edit]) => Something`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: @AlexeyRomanov's answer, below, is the correct one. I've updated this answer to include the deeper, correct information.

**Option, Some and None**

You can better understand how `Option` works with a simpler example. Here, an `Option` that is actually a `None` passes the first case and is only caught at the second level:

```
val foo: Option[String] = None

foo match {
  case x: Option[String] => "Yep! It's an option!"
  case None => "Foo is None!"
}  // res0: String = Yep! It's an option!
```

Because `None` is actually a subclass of `Option`, a `None` value will match `Option[String]`. The correct solution is to use `Some(String)`:

```
foo match {
  case Some(String) => "It's a string!"
  case None => "Foo is None!"
}  // res0: String = Foo is None!
```

This is only background, though: it seems you have a nested `Option`:

> scala.None$ cannot be cast to com.fredley.Edit

This indicates that both `pending` and `published` are not `None`, and are indeed `Option[<something>]`, but due to type erasure the match won't differentiate. For example:

```
val foo: Option[String] = None
val bar: Option[String] = Option("fubar")

for (x <- List(foo, bar)) x match {
  case x: Option[Int] => println(s"It's a string=$x")
  case None => println(s"It is None!")
  case _ => println("No match found.")
}
```

Even though it should not match `Option[Int]`, the above will print:

```
It's a string=None
It's a string=Some(fubar)
```

**Note on Conditionals**

While you can embed your conditional statements as you are now, case matching allows you to include them in the case itself:

```
val suspended = true
foo match {
  case x: Some[String] => "It's a string!"
  case None if suspended => "None but suspended!"
  case None => "Foo is None!"
}  // res0: String = None but suspended!
```

So you can convert your code to:

```
def getStatus: MyStatus = {
  (mPending, mPublished) match {
    case (None, None) => MyStatus.inactive
    case (Some(Edit), None) => MyStatus.neverPublished
    case (None, Some(Edit)) if published.get.isSuspended => MyStatus.suspended 
    case (None, Some(Edit)) => MyStatus.published
    case (_, Some(published)) if published.get.isSuspended => MyStatus.suspendedWithChanges  // We don't care about the first param, so use _, let the compiler determine the type of `published`.
    case (_, Some(published)) => MyStatus.publishedWithChanges
  }
}
```

This may or may not be easier for you to parse, but is an option if you're finding the conditional branching to be becoming opaque.

Comment: Despite being accepted, I strongly disagree with this answer. 1. The example doesn't let you see what's going on in the question, because it changes the order: the question matches `None` first. 2. Using `: Some[Edit]` pattern is just a bad idea.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov It seemed that the misunderstanding was around not understanding that `None` is still an `Option`; the example was built to demonstrate that, specifically - but I get what you're saying and it's a valid point. I admit I don't quite understand why `: Some[Edit]` is a 'bad idea', though: can you say two words why?

Comment: If that was the misunderstanding, I wouldn't expect to see "_if it gets to the last case_, neither Option should be None" in the question. For the second, see my answer.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I see what you're saying now - the edit helped. Thanks! I'm going to retract this answer.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Or... not? Had no idea I couldn't delete accepted answers. :/

Answer (score 2):

The other two current answers don't explain the real problem, unfortunately.

If `mPending` and `mPublished` have type `Option[Edit]`, your code should work, despite being very unidiomatic. But because of type erasure, `published: Option[Edit]` can only test that `published` is an `Option` (you should get a warning about unchecked type parameter when compiling it!). Since the first two lines rule out it being `None` (at least if `mPending` is an `Option`), it's a `Some` and so `published.get` returns a result. To call `isSuspended` on this result, Scala must cast it to `Edit`. But from the exception message it looks like this result is `None`; that is, `mPublished` is `Some(None)` and its real type is something like `Option[Option[Edit]]` (it could also be something like `Option[Any]`).

Now, given all this, the correct solution is close to @TheKojuEffect's:

```
def getStatus: MyStatus = {
  (mPending, mPublished) match {
    case (None, None) => MyStatus.inactive
    case (_, None) => MyStatus.neverPublished
    case (None, Some(published)) => if (published.isSuspended) MyStatus.suspended else MyStatus.published
    case (_, Some(published)) =>
      if (published.isSuspended)
        MyStatus.suspendedWithChanges
      else
        MyStatus.publishedWithChanges
  }
}
```

That is, you should use `Some(published)` pattern, *but let Scala figure out what the type of `published` is*. If the supposition above is correct, the compiler will find that it is `Option[Edit]` (or `Any`), and say it doesn't have an `isSuspended` method. After this you can figure out how to fix the code: change the lines above the match to make `mPublished` into `Option[Edit]` instead? Change the pattern to `Some(Some(published))`? Something else?

Comment: @TomMedley This is the most correct answer, and should be accepted (imo).

Answer (score 1):

Using `Some` instead of `Option` should work.

```
  def getStatus: MyStatus = {
    (mPending, mPublished) match {
      case (None, None) => MyStatus.inactive
      case (Some(pending: Edit), None) => MyStatus.neverPublished
      case (None, Some(published: Edit) => if (published.get.isSuspended) MyStatus.suspended else MyStatus.published
      case (Some(pending: Edit), Some(published:Edit)) =>
          if (published.get.isSuspended)
            MyStatus.suspendedWithChanges
          else
            MyStatus.publishedWithChanges
    }
  }
```